# Circle created using Fabric.js generates oval shape on canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am new to fabric.js, I want to create a circle using fabric and render it on canvas I have done the following code. But this code generates an Oval shaped figure which is not a perfect circle, Please let me know why is this happening.

```
this.canvasIns = new fabric.Canvas('mySampleCanvas');

var myCircle = new fabric.Circle({
      radius:50,
      borderColor: 'black',
      fill:'#fff'
    });

this.canvasIns.add(myCircle);
this.canvasIns.renderAll();
```

[image: This is how the output comes]

Comment: I had this problem a long time ago. When my memory is right your problem is not directly fabric.js, it's the way how you stretch your canvas. I will take a look at my old code for you

Answer (score 0):

Check that the height and width off your html attributes and css are the same. If you use CSS to set the size of the canvas the canvas will be stretched not resized to the CSS Values.

Example:
 - Canvas Size: 500:500, your circle: 100:100
 - CSS Size:    1000:500
 - Canvas size on screen: 1000:500, your circle: 200:100

In my case I solved the problem by adding a `<div>` around the canvas generated by fabric.js to get the desired width and height values and then setting the canvas size with javascript on pageload:

Html:

```
<div id="drawingArea">
    <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas-layer" height="500" width="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

$(window).on('load', function (e) {
    canvas.setHeight($('#drawingArea').height());
    canvas.setWidth($('#drawingArea').width());
});
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is '#drawingArea'. whose id is this?

Comment: drawingArea is just a simple <div> which was stretched to the size I really needed based on the screen size. Afterwards in the JS I set the canvas size to the size of the <div>

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem due to which I was facing the issue. It was happening because I was dynamically changing the height, width of the canvas using the following code.
Due to which the issue was occurring.

```
var canvasElement = this.myCanvas.nativeElement;
    canvasElement.style.height = canvasElement.nextElementSibling.style.height = this.canvas_css.height;
    canvasElement.style.width = canvasElement.nextElementSibling.style.width = this.canvas_css.width;
    canvasElement.style.left = canvasElement.nextElementSibling.style.left = this.canvas_css.left;
    canvasElement.style.top = canvasElement.nextElementSibling.style.top = this.canvas_css.top;
```

I removed this code and gave static style to the canvas and its working fine.